# What is the best practice for organizing similar routes and controllers in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a `routes/index.js` file where I define all my routes and import whatever controllers I need. For example, a route that I've defined might look like:

```
router.get('/cars', carsController);
```

My main question is what is the best practice for handling similar looking routes for different http methods? Should I make a completely new controller file for each http method? I feel like that could result in a lot of controller files over time. Should I reuse a single controller for all http methods and then use logic inside the controller to determine what to do? ( `if (req.method === 'GET')`, etc).

Single controller example (single, larger controller file):

```
router.get('/cars', carsController);
router.get('/cars/:id', carsController);
router.put('/cars/:id', carsController);
router.post('/cars', carsController);
router.delete('/cars/:id', carsController);
```

Multi-controller example (multiple, smaller controller files):

```
router.get('/cars', getCarsController);
router.get('/cars/:id', getCarsController);
router.put('/cars/:id', updateCarsController);
router.post('/cars', createCarsController);
router.delete('/cars/:id', deleteCarsController);
```

Is there a best practice to follow for this kind of scenario? What do you guys do in your own projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to keep all requests linked to the same resource like `cars` together in a one controller file like `cars.js` and indicate that it should be responsible for the whole `/cars` path:

```
router.use('/cars', carsController);
```

in `cars.js` you can process all desired HTTP methods:

```
router.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {
  })
  .post(function(req, res) {
  })
  .delete(function(req, res) {
  })
  .put(function(req, res) {
  });
```

OR

```
router.get('/', getCars);
router.get('/:id', getCar);
router.put('/:id', updateCar);
router.post('/', createCar);
router.delete('/:id', deleteCar);
...
function getCars(req, res) {
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Anatoly, that was super helpful! I just had a quick followup question that is somewhat related to organization. What if your route contains 2 different resources? How do you know what controller the logic should go in? For example, say you have an api defined for getting a list of cars owned by a user: `/users/:userId/cars`. Would it make more sense to put the logic in the `users` controller or the `cars` controller? I would argue the `cars` controller but I'm curious about what you would say?

Comment: It depends on tasks and how resources are related to each other. If you wish to get `cars` by different criteria along with `user/:id` then `cars` should be a parent resource. In contrary if a user has different subresources like cars, houses, flats and so on then `user` should a parent resource.